# SignalR is reconnecting every view seconds in .net 3.1 core

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, signalr

I'm using SignalR under .net 3.1 in a kubernetes cluster. When connecting to the cluster, my SignalR client is reconnecting every 1 - 5sec. My current setup:

```
.net 3.1 client --> Ambassador-Api-Gateway -> K8S -> Docker-Container
```

When starting everything locally, I've no problems with to many reconnects. The client connects to the service using the following setup:

```
Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl($"{clientBase.Url}/{ClientBase.ApiVersion}/{api}-api/{hubName}", options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(clientBase.User.Token);
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

Connection.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
Connection.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
```

I've tried to reduce the `KeepAliveInterval` and increase the `ServerTimeout` but this didn't help.

Comment: Is there any sort of error in the client side logs?
There is likely some config needed in your api gateway or K8S to allow websockets, or to allow long lived connections.

Comment: @Brennan thanks for your answer, I can't see any errors and the ingress/gateway is configured to use web-sockets: `use_websocket: true`

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [link](https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/signalr-on-kubernetes/)

You can skip the negotiation part like

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl("https://example.com/myHub", options => {
    options.SkipNegotiation = true;
    options.Transport = SignalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
})
.Build();
```

And also, for broadcasting to all clients but connected to different pods, you can use Backplane using

```
services.AddSignalR().AddStackExchangeRedis("<connection_string>");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when setting those options, I receive: `SignalR The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method`. I will take a look at it.